# How can I get NDepend to fail analysis if new calls are used to a deprecated type?

Tags: cql, ndepend

We have a type named `OldThing` which we want to deprecate over time.

We need an NDepend query/rule that says `from this point on, don't add any more calls to 'OldThing'`.

We currently use NDepend and have a baseline build for checking things like `don't make large methods even larger`.

So, we'd like to use NDepend to track any **additional** calls made to `OldThing`.  I have the following CQL query:

```
// <Name>Don't use OldThing going forwards</Name>

warnif count > 0 

let containsMethods = Methods.WithFullNameIn(
   "MyNamespace.OldType.get_Foo()",
   "MyNamespace.OldType.get_Bar()")

from m in Application.Methods.UsingAny(containsMethods) 
where m.IsUsedRecently()
select m
```

... the trouble is, it doesn't seem to work;  it doesn't find any **new** calls.

Is there a better way of doing this in NDepend (perhaps by utilising `trend metrics`)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `where m.IsUsedRecently()`, this is only for third-party method calls.

Then you need to double check that the `let` expression is matching the proper deprecated methods (you could also match them all at once by using the `ObsoleteAttribute`).

Finally you should make this rule [critical](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/critical-cqlinq-rule) and it should work :)

Comment: Thanks @Patrick.  This now reports on usages in changed files, but I'd like it to report on just 'additional' usages.  For instance, a colleague opened a file and changed it (but didn't add any *additional* calls to these methods), but the build is now broken with 5 usages of these methods.

Comment: NDepend can tell if a method is calling another method but doesn't tell  a method is calling N times another method. In this context you want to know about which new or refactored method is calling an obsolete method? (and didn't call it in baseline)

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a feature that could compare the 'count' from one build to another.  I could then add a new 'trend' query per build and then see if the count has gone up.

Comment: https://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/15027213-have-ability-to-create-rule-that-compares-trend-me